# How to Generate CELL C1 unique and random in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Here the problem case:
Say The source is **A1: A80** 
( Here https://goo.(dot).gl/OTa7gM sample file ) <-- please change .(dot). to only one dot (.)

In cell **B1** randoom need VALUE string generated from the range **A1: A80**
In cell **B2** randoom need VALUE string generated from the range **A1: A80** but not same to the **B1**
In cell **B3** need randoom VALUE string generated from the range **A1: A80** but not same to the **B1** and not same to the **B2**
In cell **B4** randoom need VALUE string generated from the range **A1: A80** but not same to the **B1, B2, B3**
...
..
.
and so on may be up to 25 rows

Next in column **C1** i need the combination / CONCATINATE of **B1: B25** (separated by comma) but in this cell **C1** must not more then 500 characters.
If more then it must trim, or better bellows the number of 480 characters.

So the goal I want to generate a maximum of 500 characters (preferably less) in an Excel cell.

***please by formula, not macro or VBS, Thank You***

Comment: Are you wanting to generate new random strings, or just randomize the order of the strings already in column A?

Comment: the final point what i need is: i need 20 up to 25 strings (not more then 480 characters) from **A1:A80**  in just one cell; say C1. But C1 will continue drag and drop C2, C3, C4 and so on.  So C1 have 20-25 unique string, as well as to cell C2, C3, C4, etc

Comment: yes you correct pnuts, want to generate long string separated by comma (, or ;). help me pnuts, thanks

Comment: 1. Anything that has to be unique is n ot random 2. You cannot generate 'random' and unique without VBA because you will require an unknown number of iterations to ensure uniqueness and every iteration will rerandomize existing values.

Comment: oke Jeep, if imposible oke no problem using VBA that's oke... plese help and thanks Jeeped